# Creating .exe from command line in installshield

Tags: file, text, command-line, exe, installshield

can we make .exe file from command line in installshield, and that .exe file will open a text file? I know how to create .exe file from Install shield UI but i'm not finding any stuff on creating an exe from command line using installshield.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Answers, if they exist, probably involve either the automation interface (ISWiProject and so forth), or the command line build (iscmdbld.exe). Maybe those keywords will help?

Comment: What is meant by "that .exe will open a text file" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your InstallShield project has release (in my examples release called "Othello Beta") which produces .exe package and you would like to build it from command line, you need to use automation. For this you would use:

**ISCmdBld.exe:** [Hot to use ISCmdBld.exe](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/ISCmdBldParam.htm) and example would be:

```
ISCmdBld.exe -p "C:\InstallShield 2012 Spring Projects\My Othello Project\Othello.ism" -r "Othello Beta" -c COMP -a "Build 245"
```

**IsSABld.exe:** This will looks like the following:

```
IsSABld.exe" -p "C:\InstallShield 2012 Spring Projects\My Othello Project\Othello.ism" -b "C:\InstallShield 2012 Spring Projects\My Othello Project" -r "Othello Beta"
```